# All pipelines failing with error TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: ca42ac35-7b58-4ac4-9c2e-41d1aa848dce

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using the SaaS Azure DevOps and this morning all pipelines starting failing with this error

```
TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: ca42ac35-7b58-4ac4-9c2e-41d1aa848dce
```

According to https://status.dev.azure.com/ there are no known outages.  I see a previous question on here that indicated it was a Microsoft issue but nothing so far on their twitter feeds and support pages.

EDIT:

Here's a sample JSON response

```
{
"$id":"1",

"innerException":null,
"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: e97f2210-35fe-4251-8451-75ed71049e3b.",
"typeName":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, System.Data",
"typeKey":"SqlException",
"errorCode":0,
"eventId":0
}
```

EDIT 2:
Apparently its just the `- checkout` command!  I ran a simple test of a pipeline with only this:

```
trigger: none

pool: some-pool

steps:
- checkout: git://MyAzureDevOpsProject/SomeRepo
```

and it fails.  Can anyone else double check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, there's [one issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1061027/internal-error-when-trying-to-run-some-pipelines.html) about this in DC forum. Some customers also encountered similar issues. We have reported it to product team, you can follow the link above to get notifications if there's any update.

**And as a workaround from [Richard Gavel](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1061024/error-trying-to-queue-a-build.html):**

Try defining the repo in yaml using [explicit resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-declared-using-a-repository-resource) instead of [Inline syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-declared-using-inline-syntax).

**Update:** Roll out is now completed. Our telemetry shows that the incident has been mitigated.
We apologize for the interruptions caused by this incident.

Comment: Thanks! We actually can't use the explicit resource syntax as these are templates and that syntax doesn't seem to work in templates.  We did end up manually doing a git clone with a command line task but would like a more permanent solution.

Comment: @Hershizer33 The details about event is tracked [here](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/190740134), our engineers are working on it to roll out of the fix. I will let you know once it's fixed, sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Hershizer33 Roll out is now completed. Our telemetry shows that the incident has been mitigated. We apologize for the interruptions caused by this incident. Please run the pipeline again to check if this issue is resolved on your side, feel free to let me know if you need any further assistance for it :)